# Controliing kibana dashboard with custom form

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, kibana

I have created a `Kibana` Dashboard in `Kibana` 4 which contains multiple visualizations that are coming from `elasticsearch` data.

Now I want to create a search option for my dashboard that takes input and display the results accordingly.

Is it possible to write something in `jquery` that could interact with my `kibana` dashboard to provide me required results.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I wrote jquery script to edit the kibana URL.This url is kept in iframe and loaded according to change in fields.

Comment: Please share your jquery code so it helps OP and other users.